# Is it possible to give more weighting to a search term in Lucene.Net

Tags: lucene.net

As per the title, I would like to give a weighting to search terms which are being sent to a Lucene.Net search.

The data is address data, so I would like to give a lower weighting to words like street and avenue, and also numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Query.SetBoost is what I was looking for.

It allows you to give a higher weighting to a query term.

Comment: Use a boost > 1 to give more weight and a boost < 1 to give less weight.